# Uploading text files into ssh account

Tags: command-line

I am using my instructor's account, connecting with ssh via terminal. I am trying to upload a text file into this account but couldn't find a command for this. I tried to copy the index of file and paste it into a file created by 'nano' command, but i think this causes some problems for my calculations. Any suggestions ?

Comment: take a look at scp or sftp. `scp file user@server:/home/username`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are at least two, no -- three options. Four options. [Amongst our options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spanish_Inquisition_%28Monty_Python%29)...

1. `scp` can be used to directly copy files, in the style of the `cp` command line:

   ```
   scp filename yourlogin@server:/target/folder
   ```
2. The `sftp` commands works like `ftp`: you start it, and then can use the ftp-style commands like `put` and `get` to transfer files back and forth. Here is a sample session:

   ```
   myname@leukothea:~/tmp4$ sftp myname@leukothea:/tmp
   Connecting to leukothea...
   Changing to: /tmp
   sftp> put log.txt
   Uploading log.txt to /tmp/log.txt
   log.txt      100%   26     0.0KB/s   00:00    
   sftp> ls
   RtmpEZgt4t
   RtmpU3qZ4z                                                            
   log.txt                                                                
   sftp> quit
   ```
3. You can use one of the numerous programs for FTP/SFTP, including `Nautilus` -- just enter `sftp://username@server:/path/to/dir` to the Location bar. Now you can just drag files to the target directory.
4. You can use `rsync` to synchronize whole folders, keeping modification times etc. This is one of the most useful commands.
5. Five, five, not four. You can use `sshfs` to mount your ssh-accessible filesystem like a network drive:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install sshfs
   mkdir ~/remote
   sshfs user@server:/path/to/dir ~/remote
   ```

   You now can navigate to the `remote` folder in your home directory and use whatever local commands or tool to copy the files.